# Unexpected behaviour of implication operator in SVA

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

There is an issue I face while using an implication operator in one of my code examples. This code can be found at  https://www.edaplayground.com/x/4fVz

**Code Summary**

1. In my code, I have defined states corresponding to each count of a counter.
2. I have defined a sequence s2_7 which is a sequence starting at (count == 2) and ending at (count == 7).

`sequence s2_7;
(state == 2) ##1 (state == 3) ##1 (state == 4) ##1 (state == 5) ##1 (state == 6) ##1 ((state == 7));
endsequence`

3. I have defined a property directive with label 'test_3:' which asserts the sequence s2_7.

`test_3: assert property ( @(posedge clk)   (state==STATE2) |=>s2_7)
    $display("%0.0t, Property s2_7 is asserted.",$time());`

4. My code prints below the line when the antecedent of the property is true.

> 35, Start property sequence s2_7 , state = STATE3

5. My code prints below the line when the sequence s2_7 has started.

> 45, Starting sequence s2_7 , state = STATE4

**Below is the output from my code.**

> ```
>               0, state = STATE1
>               25, state = STATE2
>               35, Start property sequence s2_7 , state = STATE3
>               35, state = STATE3
>               45, Starting sequence s2_7 , state = STATE4
>               45, state = STATE4
>               55, state = STATE5
>               65, state = STATE6
> ```

**Issue**

I have trouble understanding below the line of the output.

> 45, Starting sequence s2_7 , state = STATE4

Can someone explain this.

Comment: No one ever uses > correctly any more.

Comment: Simulator from different vendors are seen to give different outputs. Below is the output from a different tool .

>                    0, state = STATE1
>                   25, state = STATE2
>                   35, Start property sequence s2_7 , state = STATE2
>                   35, state = STATE3
>                   45, Starting sequence s2_7 , state = STATE3
>                   45, state = STATE4
>                   55, state = STATE5
>                   65, state = STATE6